# How can I make one function interrupt the execution of another function? I'm using Socket.IO with Node.js

Tags: node.js, websocket, socket.io, game-development

I'm creating a game with multiple rooms, each having a handler. The rooms distribute roles, and each player is supposed to play for 50 seconds. I want to add a function that listens for player disconnection so that we don't have to wait the full 50 seconds to move on to the next player.

I i found `(setInterval)` that repeat the execution of a function and on each time we check a bool `(ifPlayerStillConnected)`
Does anyone have a plan to achieve that? Thanks."